# How do i add css attributes with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, transition

how can i achieve that a the div (sellBody) is moved 50px to the left or right if clicking on the buttons left and right?

with the following code the box is only moved 50px to the left or right once. I know why but i don't know how to make it move 50px to either side EVERY time i click on either button.

```
function slideLeft(sellBody) {

  var slideLeft = document.getElementById("sellBody");
    slideLeft.style.transition = "left 1.0s linear 0s";
    slideLeft.style.left = "-50px";
}

function slideRight(sellBody) {

  var slideRight = document.getElementById("sellBody");
    slideRight.style.transition = "right 1.0s linear 0s";
    slideRight.style.right = "-50px";
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything to do with clicks in the code you provided. Is there more to it or are you using an inline `onclick` method somewhere in your HTML markup?

Answer (score 1):

> *"with the following code the box is only moved 50px to the left or right once. I know why but i don't know how to make it move 50px to either side EVERY time i click on either button."*

You would need to get the current value and subtract 50 from it:

```
var currentLeft = parseFloat(slideLeft.style.left);
slideLeft.style.left = (currentLeft - 50) + "px";
```

The current style would be in the format `"50px"`, so use [`parseFloat()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get the number and ignore the units so that you can do your subtraction, then concatenate `"px"` to the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `transition` CSS property, but you should parse the CSS attributes as integers, do your math, then re-set the properties.

For this instance, you don't need CSS's `right` at all.
You only need to change the `left` property.

For moving it left, subtract from `left`
For moving it right, add to `left`

---

```
function slideLeft(sellBody) {
  var slideLeft = document.getElementById("sellBody");
  slideLeft.style.left = Math.floor( parseInt(slideLeft.style.left, 10) - 50 ) + 'px';
}

function slideRight(sellBody) {
  var slideRight = document.getElementById("sellBody");
  slideLeft.style.left = Math.floor( parseInt(slideLeft.style.left, 10) + 50 ) + 'px';
}
```